# Using ServerSent Events for real time updates on map

Tags: javascript, php, html, mapbox, server-sent-events

I made a supereasy GPS-tracker for mobile devices saving LAT and LONG to a MySQL-database, and that part is working fine.

On a second page, Im trying to update a marker on the map in real-time, based on upates from the server via ServerSent Events. The problem is that I dont understand how the map the output of the gps-location into the javascript generating the marker.

```html
<span id="result"></span>

<script>

 if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
 var source = new EventSource("sync.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
  };
 } else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No support";
}

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([lat, long], 13);
var marker = L.marker([lat, long]).addTo(mymap);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
 attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
maxZoom: 18,
id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
tileSize: 512,
zoomOffset: -1,
accessToken: 'MyTOKEN'
}).addTo(mymap);
 </script>
```

The coordinates are coming from the sync.php-file (and gets new data from the MySQL-database). My problem is that the data is outputting it to , but I need it inside the javascript inside the var myMap and var marker.

The data from the sync-file looks like this: long, lat, 13 (long and lat as actual coordinates).

Any easy solution for this so the map location will auto-update whenever the server pushes new data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is where you need to process the incoming data and update the map:

```
source.onmessage = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
}
```

Is the `<span id="result">` showing the lat/lon being sent by the server? If so, you'll need to parse `event.data` to extract the lat/lon (maybe `event.data.lat`, `event.data.long`?)

This code doesn't seem to do anything since `lat` and `long` are not defined in this context:

```
var marker = L.marker([lat, long]).addTo(mymap);
```

Perhaps this is the code you should add to the function above, except modified to use `event.data.lat` and `event.data.long` instead of `lat` and `long`?

Comment: Thanks! The "lat" and "long" where just placed there to show where I need the data to end up. The data coming in and are now being shown in the "result" looks like this: <span id="result">[59.xxxxxxxxxxx, 10.xxxxxxxxxx], 13</span>.

Comment: In that case it looks like the long/lat are in an array, so the code to extract the longitude should probably be `event.data[0]` and latitude should be `event.data[1]`.

Comment: No, its just me creating it to look like that from sync.php. `$content = '['.$lat.', '.$long.'], 13';`

Comment: After an hour of videosupport with a friend, its finally working as wanted! Thanks for your help along the way!

Comment: @Chris-HåvardBerge Great! If my response answered your question, please consider [marking it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or upvoting it. Thanks!